# loop select results as arguments for script

Tags: sql, perl, for-loop, oracle11g, sh

I'm new to this site, and quite new to sql language too, i don't know if what i want is "possible", but here's what i need to do.

I have a script.pl which requires an argument when you execute it like this 
=> ./script.pl -a 102312 where "102312" is the argument

With an sql request, i get a column from a table in my database which gives me a list of these arguments 
=> 102312/102312/212312/... etc

I need to execute my command "./script.pl -a 'argument'" for each results of my request

I dont know if it's clear, i'm not english so sorry for that

Thanks in advance for your help
Take care

EDIT : 
Hi again,

I tried this and it's nearly working, i got my .sh script here :

```
#!/bin/bash
result=$(sqlplus ${USER}/${PWD}@${mydb}<< EOF
@script.sql)

echo $result
```

the only matter is that when i print my variable, before the actual result of the query, i get the following text **"Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With ... Testing options SQL> "** and then the query's result like this 102312 102312 212312 and then again **"Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning and Real Application Testing options"**
can i get rid off this text and only get the result of the query?, so that i can use these as arguments for my perl script.

Thanks again for your attention

EDIT 2 : i found out that i need to add "-s" arg into my sqlplus request , everything is working now thanks for your help again see ya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
Based on your comment I think you just need to use a for loop in you .sh script.  First you'd assign the query results and then use the for loop to call the .pl script for each argument in your results variable.

```
for ARG in $RESULTS
  do
     perl /path/to/script.pl $ARG
  done
```

I'm not as familiar with bash scripting so the code might not be quite right but the approach should be sound.

Original answer:

If you're query script and script.pl must be separate but are both Perl scripts you can have the query script run script.pl for you using system().
Assuming your arguments are separated by / you could do something like this in  your query script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#query code to get arguments
$arguments =~ s/\// /;

system ("perl /path/to/script.pl $arguments") or die ("Something went wrong: $?\n");
```

Then in script.pl you can just loop through @_:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

for my $arg (@_)
{
  #script.pl code
}
```

Here's the link to perldoc for using [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).  Although I'd only recommend this approach if everything is internal.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but like i answered just before, no i have .pl script that i use and that should not be touched, and i want to use .sh to execute .sql query and use the .sql query's result as an argument for my .pl execution, feel free to ask if it's still not clear i know that my english can be quite bad sometimes^^

Comment: Thanks a lot again ! i'll try to follow this path tomorrow at work :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to want to execute your script for each argument returned from your SQL query. Not seeing any of your Perl script or your SQL query makes this sort of difficult to answer, but I would suggest a slight change in how you are thinking about this problem. Instead of performing a SQL query, somehow getting the results in a textual form, then running your script N times (where N is the number of arguments returned in your SQL query). You could:

1. Modify script.pl to perform the SQL query using DBI
2. Loop over the results from your query and execute whatever action script.pl performs on each argument

That might look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict; 
use warnings; 

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
   $dsn, $user, $password, { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0 }
);
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(
   "select arguments from table where <some-condition> = ?"
);
$sth->execute( <condition> );

while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref ) {
  # execute action on row
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your very quick answer!!
I see your point, and it's true that it's way more practical, the only problem here is that i'm not the author of the .pl script, it's an old one doing many other stuffs, calling procs..etc so it has to stay how it is right now i can't change it.
I was thinking of a .sh script calling the query (i did it) but what i'm missing for now, is using the result of the query (which is only a column of N rows), and execute my .pl script N times with the N different results as argument, i dont know how to do it like i said i'm quite new to this kind of stuffs